# EventTrigger of UserControl not firing for second of multiple child UserControls

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, eventtrigger

I know how to call a Command in my ViewModel when my View loads:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestApp.Views.MyUserControl"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding OnLoadedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</UserControl>
```

This works fine.

However, I have a parent control where I put these UserControls in. This happens dynamically, i.e. I add a new UserControl when needed (a user action).

My problem is that the OnLoadedCommand is executed the first time I add a UserControl, but not anymore in subsequent adds. If I remove all UserControls, and re-add, the same thing happens: executed for the first UserControl, no longer for any subsequent UserControls.

How can I make a call to my ViewModel for every UserControl separately?

Answer (score 1):

I took your control code and tried it, got as many calls as I added controls.

I did a simple 'for' loop with initialization of several controls being added.
I tried setting datacontext from one main viewmodel, and separate viewmodels for each controls, both attempts worked fine.

Command is clearly being called. therefore there is clearly a problem with command binding. Try looking into datacontext set for other controls, or alteration of viewmodel after first call (if they share one viewmodel instance).

Comment: Yes, I dumbed down the example too much. Further investigation leads me to believe this has something to do with Virtualization and the Telerik control I'm using (RadDocking). I've also put it on the [Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/virtualization-and-datatemplates).